# Every File shared with same person

Tags: network-shares, shared-folders

At work, Windows 7. It seems every file / folder I create is shared with this one admin who installed something on my PC a long time ago. I can remove them from every individual file, but it's not a global change. They are not even a user on the machine. How can this person be removed? (I am an semi-admin on my PC)

The person in question has no idea either.

Comment: My guess: His permissions are set in a higher level folder and when you create a new file it inherits from above.  When you remove him form a file, what are the EXACT steps you have to take to do it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 If it's a folder, I can right click it and go to Sharing > Share > and remove it. If I go into the Security tab it does not let me.

Comment: "If I go into the Security tab it does not let me", it does not let you what? If you try to remove his permissions via the security tab, what does it tell you? Also, your question/problem is a little confusing, as you can't "Share" files directly, only folders.

Comment: Under the security tab, it lists all the users in a share but it says that it can't remove because "this object is inheriting permissions from its parent." so what folder would that be? I would guess c:\users\username

Comment: It'd be the permissions on the folder that file/folder is in, or the one above it, or the one above that, etc.  Also, are you only talking about files created in your user's profile folder (\Users\yourUsername), or is this happening with files you create anywhere on the drive?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It seems my \Users\YourUserName is the only one that has the share. Anyone else who logs in and gets their own profile does not have the issue.

Comment: Talk to your admin and have him remove the inherent properties. If he doesn't know "how" or whatever the case may be, create a new profile and transfer everything over to the new one since new accounts don't seem to be affected.